# how to retrieve data from database using select query

Tags: vb.net

I have to retrieve data in two TextBoxes but the data should belong to `tokennum` that I am getting from first text box. I have a total of three TextBoxes and one button. In a database called `db1` I have a table named `Table1` and two fields `ser` as serial number, `tokennum` for token number and `name` for name of employees.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Dim dbProvider As String
        Dim dbSource As String
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim sql As String
        Dim a As Integer



        dbProvider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
        dbSource = "Data Source = C:\Documents and Settings\trainee-ng-it\Desktop\Subhedar Sir\New Folder (2)\db1.mdb"

        con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource

        con.Open()
        a = Val(TextBox1.Text)
        sql = "SELECT Table1.ser FROM Table1 where Table1.token num=a"
        da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
        da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
        da.Fill(ds, "db1")
        MsgBox("Database is now open")

        con.Close()
        MsgBox("Database is now Closed")



    End Sub
End Class
```

@dhruva sir:thanks for guidance,i corrected that but now how to proceed?how to get respective data in the correspoding textboxes?

Comment: Maybe you haven't used Sqlcommand.ExecuteScalar before?

Answer (score 0):

Your sql query is wrong

```
    sql = "SELECT Table1.ser FROM Table1 where Table1.token num=a"
```

It should be something like this :

```
    sql = "SELECT Table1.ser FROM Table1 where Table1.tokennum=" & a
```

Although the 'Table1.token num' is wrong, there cannot be a space within a column name, I hope that was just a typo and have corrected the same in the second query.

Comment: sir:thanks for guidance,i corrected that but now how to proceed?how to get respective data in the correspoding textboxes?

Comment: @teena gupta, please go through the .net documentation. it's really straight forward, please don't expect me to do your work.

Answer (score 0):

```
"SELECT Table1.ser FROM Table1 where Table1.tokennum= " + a
```

This is a start, but your question is not very clear